# Crashlytics recordException not working for custom exception with cause parameter included

Tags: android, crashlytics

I need to log an exception to Crashlytics from a Kotlin Result.onFailure.

The following works (where it is a throwable)

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(it)
```

This also works

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(MyCustomException("test message"))
```

where custom exception is

```
class MyCustomException(message: String) : Exception(message)
```

However this doesn't get logged to Crashlytics

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(MyCustomException(it))
```

where

```
class MyCustomException(t: Throwable) : Exception(t)
```

So it seems that including a cause parameter means it's not logged to Firebase. Anybody know why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I since discovered that my exceptions were being logged to Crashlytics. The problem was that they weren't easily discoverable.

If there's an exception with a cause, only the cause is findable in the Crashlytics Console. For example if I have

```
class MyOuterException(t: Throwable) : Exception(t)
```

and I do

```
.recordException(MyOuterException(MyInnerException()))
```

Then only `MyInnerException` will be displayed in the list of Exceptions in Crashlytics. Furthermore, even if I search for `MyOuterException` it won't display any results.